Python Flask Blueprint routes always print request and response content
In my Python Flask app I use Blueprint route to serve and handle API requests.
app/init.py
from api.foo import foo_route
def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(foo_route)
    ...
    return app

api/foo.py
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify
foo_route = Blueprint("foo", __name__)

@foo_route.route("/path/to/foo/API", methods=["POST"])
def handle_foo_api(request):
    result = {"foo1": "foo1", "foo2": "foo2"}
    return jsonify(result), 200

How can I print all API request headers/body and response headers/body?
I can print it inside each function. For example, to print the request header for function handle_foo_api:
@foo_route.route("/path/to/foo/API", methods=["POST"])
def handle_foo_api(request):
    logger.info(f"handle_foo_api request headers: {request.headers}")
    logger.info(f"handle_foo_api request data: {request.json}")
    result = jsonify({"foo1": "foo1", "foo2": "foo2"})
    logger.info(f"handle_foo_api response headers: {resp.headers}")
    logger.info(f"handle_foo_api response data: {resp.get_json()}")
    return result, 200

But I would like to do it once and for all, instead of in each function. How can I do that?

The before_request decorator docs

before_request and after_request can work as @PGHE indicated in the comment.
In app/init.py, I added the following code and it worked as I expected. Now I can see all request/response headers and body printed.
from flask import Flask, request
from api.foo import foo_route
def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(foo_route)

    ...

    @app.before_request
    def before_request_func():
        logger.info(f"{request.path} API request headers: {request.headers}")
        req_body = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        if _is_valid_json(req_body):
          logger.info(f"{request.path} API request data: {json.dumps(json.loads(req_body), indent=4)}") 

    @app.after_request
    def after_request_func(response):
        logger.info(f"{request.path} API response headers: {response.headers}")
        resp_body = response.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        if _is_valid_json(resp_body):
          logger.info(f"{request.path} API response data: {json.dumps(json.loads(resp_body), indent=4)}") 
        return response

    return app

